# plotting line between points in a loop goes wrong

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to simulate a random walk. The idea is to choose a random number between `0` and `2*pi` and let the random walker go in that direction. Here is what I tried to do to simulate such a random walk:

```
before=[0 0]; %start in (0,0)
while 1
    x=rand;
    x=x*2*pi; %// choose random angle
    increment=[cos(x),sin(x)] %// increments using the sine and cosine function
    now=before+increment;
    plot(before, now)
    hold on
    before=now;
    pause(1);
end
```

I expect this program to plot lines and each new line starts at the ending point of the previous line, but this does not happen. I have no clue why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the syntax for `plot` wrong, which is `plot(X,Y)`. Change the call to

```
plot([before(1), now(1)], [before(2), now(2)])
```

and your program should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an **improved version** that does all the calculation **vectorized** and gives you two choices of output. The first one displays all at once and is **very fast**. The second one takes a lot of time depending on the amount of samples.

```
pts = [0,0];                % starting point
N   = 10000;                % sample count
x   = rand(N,1) * 2*pi;     % random angle

% calculate increments and points
inc = [cos(x),sin(x)];
pts = [pts;cumsum(inc,1)];

% plot result at once
figure;
plot(pts(:,1),pts(:,2));

% plot results in time steps
figure; hold on;
for i = 1:size(pts,1)
    plot(pts(i:i+1,1),pts(i:i+1,2))
    pause(1)
end
```

Here is an example of the output:
[image: all at once]